# Google pay "the transaction may be risky. For your safety, it can't be completed at this time" what i do to remove this here is code

Tags: google-pay

I am using this to get payment through google pay but after entering upi it gave the error:

> the transaction may be risky. For your safety, it can't be completed at this time

Here is my code:
`<a href="upi://pay?pa=gpay-xxxxxx@okbizaxis&amp;pn=Razorpay&amp;tn=thanks for booking&amp;am=6000&amp;cu=INR&amp;mc=5411&amp;tr=1612286108279" onclick="this.href=this.href.split('?')[0]+'/pay?pa=gpay-xxxxxx@okbizaxis&amp;pn=Razorpay&amp;tn=You Won&amp;am=6000&amp;cu=INR&amp;mc=5411&amp;tr='+new Date().getTime()"></a>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am also facing same issue, any solutions yet?

Comment: no, not yet have you got?